# Does a cocompact subgroup of a topological group contain a cocompact normal subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups

**Motivation:** It is obvious that for a finite index subgroup $H$ of a group $G$, there exists a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$, $K\subset H$, with $|G/K|<\infty$.

**Our question:** Let $G$ be a topological group and $H$ be a closed but not necessarily normal subgroup of $G$ such that the quotient topological space $G/H$ is a compact space. Does there exist a closed subgroup $K\subset H$ which is normal in $G$ such that $G/K$ is a compact topological group?

**Remark:** One can consider a similar problem in the context of rings and algebras: see [this follow-up question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355271/when-a-finite-codimensional-subalgebra-contains-a-finite-codimension-ideal).

Comment: Uniform lattices in $SL_3(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  Put $G=H=\mathbb{R}$ and $K=\{0\}$ then $G/K$ is not a continuous image of $G/H$. Right?

Comment: @MarkSapir may I ask you to ellaborate your comment or write a complete answer? Thank you.

Comment: @AliTaghavi a non-compact simple connected Lie group $G$ has no proper normal cocompact subgroup. But it has cocompact lattices, and also has connected cocompact proper subgroups (e.g., upper triangular matrices in $\mathrm{SL}_{n\ge 2}$ of $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$).

Comment: @YCor what other structures are appropriate for consideration of this concept.  For example: which Lie algebras satisfies the following: every finite codimensional sub lie algebra contains a finite codinensional ideal. Or in the context if $C^*$ algebras: Which $C^*$ algebras satisfy the following property? Every finite codimensional subalgebra contains a finite codimension ideal. All of these properties are inspired by the initial group theoretical concept.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi In fact $G/H$ is the continuous image of $G/K$ not converse situation.

Comment: The situation now that the title and the question are answered in comments, while the "remark" asks a more complicated and distinct question. I'd suggest to either **(a)** ask the "remark" in separate question (in which case I could answer this one with a cw answer to make the question settled) or **(b)** change the current "remark" into the main question (changing the title in particular) giving the original question and its easy examples only as context. I think (a) is a better solution (since these are quite drastic changes).

Comment: @YCor  yes I see. Very good siggestion. I do (a).

Comment: @YCor  Thanks for your suggestion. I add a new question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355271/when-a-finite-codimensional-subalgebra-contains-a-finite-codimension-ideal

Answer (score 3):

No: the answer is often negative in the non-discrete case.

For instance, non-compact simple connected Lie group $G$ has no proper normal cocompact subgroup. But it has cocompact lattices, and also has connected cocompact proper subgroups (e.g., upper triangular matrices in $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ or $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{C})$, for $n\ge 2$).