# When a finite codimensional subalgebra contains a finite codimension ideal?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

What is a classification of all algebras $A$ (purely algebraic algebras, Banach or $C^*$ algebras or Lie algebras) with the following property:

> Every finite codimensional subalgebra $B$ of $A$ contains a  subalgebra $I$ such that $I$ is an ideal in $A$ and $A/I$ is a finite dimensional algebra.

One can ask a similar question  for "Rings" but consider finite quotient rather than finite codimensionality in algebra case.

This question is inspired by  [this post and its comments conversation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355036/does-a-cocompact-subgroup-of-a-topological-group-contain-a-cocompact-normal-subg)

Comment: What do you mean by classification? And why are you interested in this?

Comment: @MarkSapir  The motivation for this question is the pure group theoric problem written in the attached link you find in this pist "every finit index subgroup contains a finit index normal sibgroup". By classification I mean some results as "An algebra has this property if ......"  or " An algebra has this property  if and only if it satisfies......". Or some examples or counter examples.

Comment: What is a connection between the group theory problem and rings, $C*$-algebras and Lie algebras? An algebra has this property if it is finite or with 0-product (the product of any two elements is 0), or if  every subalgebra of it is an ideal. A finite non-trivial field extension of an infinite field is a counterexample. There are lots of other similar trivial statements. I guess that is what you call "a classification".

Comment: @MarkSapir  I think you are collecting some (and not all ) sufficient conditions which looks trivial. A classification is a  "iff" theorem. For example I think  it is the case for commutative unital $C^*$ algebra. Do you have a counter example? Moreover  what about Lie algebra case?

Comment: In my opinion, a possible classification of Lie algebras with the required property is hopeless. However, it is worth mentioning that examples of infinite-dimensional simple Lie algebras containing  subalgebras of finite codimension were constructed by Amayo in a paper published in the Proc. Lond. Math. Soc. in 1976. On the other hand, by a Theorem of Kukin, if a restricted Lie algebra $L$ over a field of characteristic $p>0$ contains a restricted subalgebra of finite codimension, then $L$ also contains a restricted ideal of finite codimension,

Comment: @SalvatoreSiciliano Thank you very much for your very interesting comment. I was not aware of the concept "restricted Lie algebra"